# Issue while adding values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Please read again till end (description updated)
I want something like this.
ex : 
if (7200 / 42) is float then
floor(7200/42) + [7200 - {(floor(7200/42)) * 42}] / 10 ^ length of [7200 - {(floor(7200/42)) * 42}]
STEP : 1 =>  171 + ((7200 - (171*42))/10 ^ len(7200-7182))
STEP : 2 =>  171 + ((7200 - 7182)/10 ^ len(18))
STEP : 3 =>  171 + (18/10 ^ 2)
STEP : 4 =>  171 + (18/100)
STEP : 5 =>  171 + 0.18
STEP : 6 =>  171.18

I have written the code in SQL which actually works perfectly but the addition of 171 + 0.18 only gives 171

**IF I can get "171/18" instead of "171.18" as string then it'd also be great. (/ is just used as separator and not a divison sign)**

Following is the code I written
Here,
(FAP.FQTY + FAP.QTY) = 7200,
PRD.CRT = 42
(values only for example)

```
select 
case when PRD.CRT <> 0 then
    case when (FAP.FQTY + FAP.QTY)/PRD.CRT <> FLOOR((FAP.FQTY + FAP.QTY)/PRD.CRT) then --DETERMINE WHETHER VALUE IS FLOAT OR NOT
        (floor((FAP.FQTY + FAP.QTY)/PRD.CRT)) +
        ((FAP.FQTY + FAP.QTY) - floor((FAP.FQTY + FAP.QTY)/PRD.CRT) * PRD.CRT) /
        POWER(10, len(floor((FAP.FQTY + FAP.QTY) - floor((FAP.FQTY + FAP.QTY)/PRD.CRT) * PRD.CRT))) 
    else 
        (FAP.FQTY + FAP.QTY)/PRD.CRT -- INTEGER
    end 
else
    0
end
from FAP inner join PRD on FAP.Comp_Year = PRD.Comp_Year and
FAP.Comp_No = PRD.Comp_No and FAP.Prd_Code = PRD.Prd_Code
```

I got all the values correct till 171 + 0.1800 correct but after that I am only receiving 171 in the addition.  I want exactly 171.18.

**REASON FOR THIS CONFUSING CALCULATION**
Its all about accounting
Suppose, a box(or a cartoon) has 42 nos. of items.
A person sends 7200 items. how many boxes he has to send?
So that will be (7200/42) = 171.4257.
But boxes cannot be cut (its whole number i.e 171).
so 171 * 42 ie 7182 items. 
Remaining items = 7200 - 7182 = 18.
So answer is 171 boxes and 18 items. 
In short 171.18 or "171/18"

Please help me with this..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by  `if (7200 / 42) is float`? As written in your pseudo code fragment, 7200/42 has as a result an INT of value 171.

Comment: I think instead of `float` you should use the term `decimal`. They are sort of the same, but not really. `float` has some major caveats and it's really not exactly what you are after here. I can't really figure out the "Why" part of your question. Why would you want to do this? Just push everything to decimal and have whatever application is consuming truncate any decimal it doesnt want.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Its not round(), I know that but I actually need like this. Its actually accounting thing I need. Is there any other way to get the what I want?

Comment: And Totally not following the logic where `7200/42` is `171.18`. What sense does that make? Where/why is that .18?

Comment: @TT. if (7200/42) is float i.e float then it should run a part of code else the other part of code. I written in such a way only to make it understandable. Its not actual sql code.

Comment: One thing to look at is if there's an INT that's divided by an INT where you expect decimals in the resulting number.  Because an INT divided by an INT returns an INT, hence no decimals.  One trick is to cast one INT used in the division to a float, or multiply it with 1.0

Comment: @JNevill 7200/42 is not 171.18. I ain't said that. 7200/42 is 171.42857.... but I want 171.18 as value which I acquired in above steps

Comment: @LukStorms But I got the values till last second step. I.e 171 + 0.18 
Then it should be easy just to add and give 171.18 I don't understand why it only gives 171.. Floor function is used under the brackets and addition is out of it

Comment: @AndrewMorton its not rounding thing actually. I don't want round and all stuff.

Comment: To check if `x / y` would return decimals, you could just do a modulus check.  `case when (x % y) > 0 then ...`

Comment: I am not clear in your steps. But I found you are wrong in Mathematics steps. Kindly apply [BODMAS](https://www.skillsyouneed.com/num/bodmas.html) on `step 2:`

Comment: @HiteshShroff Then your wording should probably be, `if 42 is not a divisor of 7200`, or `if 7200 divided by 42 has decimal digits`. Just to make your question a bit clearer :).

Comment: Is my answer of "have the integral portion of the division, then a `.` (or `/`) and then the remainder from the division" not correct (and a far simpler description of your problem, if I've understood it correctly)?

Comment: @IdontKnowEnglish Oh ya, sorry , I rectify it. That's just missing brackets. but believe me, I coded properly in sql, if you can check it..

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am even confused what you said. But wait, I add a description of why I want. I guess later you'll understand properly what I want. Please wait for some minutes. Thank you

Comment: They're standard mathematical terms. When working in integers, the result of a division will be the `quotient` (here, 171) and the `remainder` (the left over bits, here 18). You want to present these two numbers, separated by a `.`, do you not?

Comment: @HiteshShroff.. Okay.. let me try

Comment: @IdontKnowEnglish see the reason I added in the description to understand the problem more properly.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever see the reason I added in the description to understand the problem more properly.

Comment: Yes. My answer does this. It wouldn't be confusing if you a) learnt the appropriate terms relating to mathematical division and b) weren't trying to solve it *mathematically* past a certain point where we're not really dealing with numbers any more.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever okay so I try it and tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just another idea about how to calculate it.

Simple calculate the whole boxes.
And concatinate a dot with the remaining items (using a modulus).
Wrapped it all up in a CASE WHEN (or IIF) to avoid the divide by zero.

**Example snippet:**

```
declare @TestTable table (FQTY numeric(18,2), QTY numeric(18,2), CRT numeric(18,0));

insert into @TestTable (FQTY,QTY,CRT) values 
(5000, 2200, 42),
(5000, 2200, 0),
( 100,  200, 10);

select *,
 (CASE
  WHEN CRT>0
  THEN CONCAT(CAST(FLOOR((FQTY+QTY)/CRT) as INT),'/',CAST((FQTY+QTY)%CRT as INT))
  ELSE '0'
  END) AS Boxes
from @TestTable;
```

**Result:**

```
FQTY    QTY     CRT  Boxes
------- ------- ---  ------
5000.00 2200.00  42  171/18
5000.00 2200.00   0       0
 100.00  200.00  10    30/0
```

The CONCAT returns a varchar, and so does the CASE WHEN.
But you could wrap that CASE WHEN in a CAST.

Comment: @HiteshShroff An afterthought.  If you'd want it in the 'ddd/d' format then the cast to float won't be needed.

Comment: your answer gives me error converting varchar to float. Can you tell me something like converting to string? I tried str,convert(varchar(10),data) etc. functions but its gives me 0.18000000000000 instead of 0.18... before applying str or convert, I get 0.18 but after conversion to string, it changes to 0.1800000000000.

Comment: @HiteshShroff The current version of this answer does assume that those columns are all INT's.  So a question, what are the data types of those columns?

Comment: FQTY and QTY are numeric(18,2) & CRT is numeric(18,0)

Comment: Think that I want to change it to String and not integers or float or others...
And concat it

Comment: @HiteshShroff The example snippet now works for your data types.  Using FLOOR and CAST to INT.  It now returns a varchar.

Comment: I am getting this value '171.180000000000000000000'... Can't it be just 171.18...
 Or '171/18' .. A '/' would be best than '.' … I tried to change '.' with '/' in example snippet and I get error conversion varchar to numeric.....

Comment: @HiteshShroff That shouldn't be in the latest version of my answer. It casts the results to INTEGER and then uses CONCAT to stich them together.  Even if you change the '.' to '/', it'll return a varchar. Of course, you can't CAST something like '123/4' to a number.

Comment: No ssly. that's the latest you updated... getting the same '171.180000000000000000000'... and how shall I add '/' instead of '.'

Comment: Could it be that you insert or update the result to some numeric type in a table. Like f.e. a NUMERIC(50,40) ? And when you select from that you get all those 0? Are you using SMSS to test this? Or some programming language. 
 Or did you add an extra CONVERT to the Boxes result?  Btw, if you look at my snippet. If you want a '/' then just replace that `,'.',` in the CONCAT?

Comment: [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlEp4GyzKDzFiqZR5Mh0d1bgu2hSyA)
 Please check the link. I used snippet like you. 
Yes I am using SSMS. I am getting error displayed in the link. Sorry for delayed reply

Comment: @HiteshShroff Your query needs 1 small change. It's because the ELSE returns the integer 0 `ELSE 0 END` while it should return a string `ELSE '0' END`. Now it tries to convert '171/18' to an integer because the ELSE returns an integer.

Comment: dayum this... I am sooo dumb.. Well, it worked.. Thanx friend

Answer (score 1):

Recognise that you're not producing an actual numeric result, I'd describe it as *unhealthy* to try to keep it using such a datatype<sup>1</sup>.

This produces the *strings* you're seeking, if I've understood your requirement:

```
;With StartingPoint as (
    select 7200 as Dividend, 42 as Divisor
)
select
    CONVERT(varchar(10),Quotient) +
        CASE WHEN Remainder > 0 THEN '.' + CONVERT(varchar(10),Remainder)
        ELSE '' END as FinalString
from
    StartingPoint
        cross apply
    (select Dividend/Divisor as Quotient, Dividend % Divisor as Remainder) t
```

(Not tested for negative values. Some adjustments may be required. Technically `%` computes the modulus rather than the remainder, etc)

---

<sup>1</sup>Because someone might try and add two of these values together and I doubt that produces a correct result, not even necessarily if using the same `Divisor` to compute both.

Comment: Okay I got it... Just added convert to quotient.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your logic correctly you want the remainder of 7200 divide by 42 and the remainder is to divide by 100

```
declare 
    @dividend   int = 7200,
    @divisor    int = 42

select  (@dividend / @divisor) 
+       convert(decimal(10,4), 
                (@dividend % @divisor) * 1.0 / power(10, len(@dividend % @divisor)))
```

EDIT: change to handle the `10^len(remainder)`

Comment: If you look at the logic more closely, they're trying to produce *as many* digits after the decimal as are required to contain the remainder (e.g. the `10^len(remainder)` part)

Comment: Nope, if (7200 / 42) has remainder then just take quotient till you can calculate in integers). if it has remainders then take the quotient and multiply it with divisor. i.e (quotient * divisor)  = (171 * 42) = 7182(a1). then dividend - a1 => 7200-7182 = 18. I want this 18 after . or "/" of quotient i.e 171.18 or 171/18. No matter if it become string

Comment: I know its damn tricky and confusing why I need but believe me, it is used in somewhere. I shall update the reason for it soon.

Comment: can you provide another example ?

Comment: Check the question again. I updated the reason below in the description. It might help you understand why I need such a data.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an automatic type conversion from int to decimal(10,0) which is probably not what you want.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Check out the "Caution" box.

If you want a specific amount of precision, you'll need to explicitly cast() the values to the desired data type.

Comment: Okay but there should be a way to get the desired answer. Please read the question again, I updated a little bit. It'd be great if I get a string. Thanx for your answer

Comment: You have the answer in a couple of places here. When doing floating point match, you need to specify the input data as the correct data type, either by creating the correct column definition(s) or by using cast/convert to make them the right data type. Once you do that, your math will work.

Comment: ok so according to you I am doing (Integer + float) will yield to 'integer'. To get answer, I need to do like (float + float).. Is it so?

Comment: Okay I got it... Just added convert to quotient. You're right